# Should I revert factors to numeric form, manually?

Tags: r, dataframe, type-conversion

```
HF$anaemia = as.factor(HF$anaemia)
HF$diabetes = factor(HF$diabetes,levels=c(0,1),labels=c("Absent","Present"))
HF$hypertension = factor(HF$high_blood_pressure,levels=c(0,1),labels=c("Absent","Present"))
HF$sex = factor(HF$sex,levels=c(0,1),labels=c("Female","Male"))
HF$smoking = factor(HF$smoking,levels=c(0,1),labels=c("No","Yes"))
HF$DEATH_EVENT = as.factor(HF$DEATH_EVENT)

HF <- select(HF, -high_blood_pressure)

nrow(HF)
[1] 299
```

So this is the code I ran to adjust my variables before I began analyzing my current dataset. I'm at a point where I want to perform Cox Regression using `My.stepwise::My.stepwise.coxph()`, which requires all my variables to be numeric-- the way they were before I ran the code above.

I don't have industry experience yet and would like to know if the proper way to adjust my variables back to numeric form would be to do so manually... or is making a copy of the original dataset good enough?

Could the answer possibly be that "yes, it'd be ideal to revert back manually with a large dataset but since this one only has 299 observations, it's fine to make a copy"?

Comment: What is your concern about copying the original dataset? Why would this be “improper” or not “ideal”? This seems like an opinion-based question, which is considered off-topic for SO.

Answer (score 1):

If we need the `factor` columns to be `integer`, an option is to loop over the `factor` columns and use `as.integer`

```
HF2 <- HF
i1 <- sapply(HF, is.factor)
HF2[i1] <- lapply(HF, as.integer)
```

Comment: But this defeats the purpose, does it not? I'd be copying the data frame with the first line of code.

Comment: @Antonio I created the copy in case you wanted to keep the original values.  My code is to show that you can do the changes to numeric automatically from `factor` columns

Answer (score 1):

With dplyr

```
library(tidyverse)

HF %>% 
  mutate(across(where(is.factor), as.numeric))
```